# What is the solution for 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 0'?

Tags: python, deep-learning

My professor gave me these things and told me to run it. He told me load the data using Custom Data Loader and told me to analyze the result of the dataloader.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torch.utils.data import Dataset 
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset): 
  def __init__(self, phase='train'):
   f = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
   data = f.to_numpy()
   if phase=='train':
     data=data[:600,:]
   if phase=='val':
     data=data[601:,:]

   self.x_data = np.array(data[:,0:11], dtype=np.float)
   self.x_data = ( self.x_data -  self.x_data.min(axis=0)) / ( self.x_data.max(axis=0) -  self.x_data.min(axis=0))

   self.y_data = data[:, 11:12]
   self.y_data=np.array(self.y_data, dtype=np.long)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.x_data)


  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x = torch.Tensor(self.x_data[idx]) 
    y = torch.LongTensor(self.y_data[idx])
    return x, y

batch_=10
dataloader ={ 'train' :  DataLoader(CustomDataset(phase='train'), batch_size=batch_, shuffle=True),
               'val' :  DataLoader(CustomDataset(phase='val'), batch_size=batch_, shuffle=False)
 }


## Define the NN architecture
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9, 50)    
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)   
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # flatten image input
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.fc3(x))
        return x

model = Net() 
loss_fn =  torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001) 

nb_epochs = 600

for epoch in range(0, nb_epochs):
  avg_cost = 0
  sample_size = 0
  avg_cost_ = 0
  sample_size_ = 0

  # Train
  for batch_idx, samples in enumerate(dataloader['train']):
    x_train, y_train = samples

    pred = model(x_train)
    loss = loss_fn(pred, y_train[:,1])

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    avg_cost+=loss
    sample_size+=1

  # Val
  for batch_idx, samples in enumerate(dataloader['val']):
    x_train, y_train = samples
    pred = model(x_train)
    loss = loss_fn(pred, y_train[:,0])
    avg_cost_+=loss
    sample_size_+=1
  
  print("epoch :" , epoch, "loss_train", avg_cost/sample_size, "loss_val", avg_cost_/sample_size_ )
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:27: DeprecationWarning: `np.long` is a deprecated alias for `np.compat.long`. To silence this warning, use `np.compat.long` by itself. In the likely event your code does not need to work on Python 2 you can use the builtin `int` for which `np.compat.long` is itself an alias. Doing this will not modify any behaviour and is safe. When replacing `np.long`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:56: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0ebd9f89baed> in <module>
     74 
     75     pred = model(x_train)
---> 76     loss = loss_fn(pred, y_train[:,0])
     77 
     78     optimizer.zero_grad()

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 0
```

What's the problem and what should I do with those codes?

Here is an extract of diabetes.csv.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an extract (some rows at least) of the _diabetes.csv_ file

Comment: I added some extract of the diabete.csv.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you extract features vs labels from your data.

You do so by:

```py
self.x_data = np.array(data[:,0:11], dtype=np.float)
...
self.y_data = data[:, 11:12]
```

This means that your features are the first 11 columns (0 to 10 included) and your labels are in the 12th column.

Your data though only has 9 columns so the labels end up as an empty array (with 0 columns). This is why then you do `y_train[:,0]` (getting the first column) you get the error (there is no first column).

To fix this just change the columns in the Dataset:

```py
self.x_data = np.array(data[:,0:8], dtype=np.float)
...
self.y_data = data[:, 8:9]
```

And of course change the dimension of the first layer of the network accordingly:

```py
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8, 50)
```